# Problem interacting with elements inside an iframe

Tags: ruby, web-scraping, watir

I'm able to retrieve data inside an iframe using

```
browser.iframe
```

But when I try to interact with elements inside this iframe, like for ex. click on a button, watir won't locate any of them.

I tried with all kind of elements inside this iframe, but nothing happens.

Comment: please share the code you are trying. Quick explanation of how Watir works with iframes is here - http://watir.com/guides/frames/

Answer (score 0):

There could be more than one iframe on your page so you might be targeting the wrong one (just writing `browser.iframe` will target the first iframe on page.

You can could inspect the page and check if there are more than one iframe, or type:

```rb
puts "there are #{browser.iframes.count} on page"
```

and run the script again.

ideally iframe has an `id` so you could write

```rb
my_iframe = browser.iframe(id: "something")
my_iframe.buttons.last.click
# or
my_iframe.button(text: "ok").click
```

if it's not a secret, right click => inspect page you are automating and screenshot/paste html here. Or share the whole code that doesn't work for you.